# Trying to make a variable check something inside an array

Tags: c++

Here is my function

```
bool ft_numchecksingle(string user_num, int arr[])
    {
        bool check = false;
        int mynum = stoi(user_num.substr(2, -1));
        int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
        for (int x = 0; x <= len; x++)
        {
            if (mynum == arr[x])
                check = true;
        }
        return (check);
    }
```

Here is the Array

```
    int arr[] = { 213, 220, 560, 890 };
```

It should return true if I enter anything within that array, however, if I enter 560 or 890 it always returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't determine the size of an array from an argument given to a function, as the array parameter will [decay to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/10871073).

So, in your `ft_numchecksingle` function, the following line:

```c
int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

will assign to `len` the size of a *pointer-to-int* (presumably, 8 bytes, on your platform) divided by the size of an `int` (presumably, 4 bytes); this will (in your case) be the value `2`, which is why your function is only searching the first two elements of the array. *[Actually, when considering the point I made in the "EDIT" below, it is more likely that the pointer is only 4 bytes, so the 'len' value is `1` in your case - you will then check only the first two elements, as you have `x <= len` in your `for` loop!]*

As your code is `C++`, you should be using the `std::vector` [container class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), instead of a 'raw' array; you can then use the `.size()` member of that class to determine to the size of the 'array'.

Alternatively, if you really must use a raw array type, then you will need to add that array's size as an extra parameter to your function, as follows:

```cpp
bool ft_numchecksingle(string user_num, int arr[], size_t len)
```

And then, in your `main` (or wherever you call that function from), you can use code like this:

```cpp
int arr[] = { 213, 220, 560, 890 };
//...
bool test = ft_numchecksingle("560", arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
//...
```

(Note that, here, the compiler can correctly calculate the `sizeof(arr)` value!)

EDIT: As an important aside, and assuming you have the *actual* size of the array in the `len` variable, then the last element of that array will have the index `len - 1` (*not* `len`). So, your `for` loop should be:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
```

rather than:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x <= len; x++) // When "x" EQUALS "len" you will be out-of-bounds!
```

Comment: How do I add the array size as an extra parameter?

Comment: @Noodlez See edit! The  `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` operation will work when used in the same scope as the declaration of `arr`.